# When measuring scalability, should you split the workload across multiple clients, or give all clients the same workload?

Tags: database, scalability, load-testing

When measuring horizontal scalability for a database, should you:

1. Split the workload across multiple clients, giving each client an even portion of the total workload? (e.g. workload per client = `w/(num of clients))`, or
2. Give all clients the same workload, thus increasing the total workload? (e.g. workload per client = `w`)

Answer (score 0):

This will be in accord with your environment behaviour, you need reproduce the real behaviour of your client(the same workload or with variations) and increase the workload until the number wanted.